# Minecraft forge problems

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to run mods on Minecraft forge 1.20.1 47.2.0

I keep getting exit code one with the crash log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff90d443ca0, pid=5572, tid=25448
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-8035246 (17.0.8+7) (build 17.0.8+7-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-8035246 (17.0.8+7-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed      oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [atio6axx.dll+0x193ca0]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://aka.ms/minecraftjavacrashes
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Would appreciate any help!

I tried re installing java to the latest version reinstalling the Minecraft launcher and removing all the mods. Nothing has worked

Comment: Show us the (relevant) code of your mod where it happens so we can know what's going on.

Comment: You have a graphics-driver-related crash.

Comment: Yes, this error happens very commonly on (integrated) AMD GPUs. Afaik it only affects forge, for whatever reason. If possible, you can try fabric.